# UIElement.Focus() does not work, why?

Tags: wpf, button, click, focus

My WPF window has a `Button` and a `ListView`.  On the `Button`'s click event, it has the following code.

```
private void myButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem()
    {
        Content = "Hello",
        Focusable = true,
        IsEnabled = true
    };
    this.listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
    lvi.Focus();
}
```

Here is the problem, the focus cannot move to `lvi(ListViewItem)`, after the user clicks the `Button`.  The code `lvi.Focus()` does not have any effect. Can someone tell me why it happens, and how can I solve it?

**Update:**

Find the solution. call this code, otherwise the focus is still captured by the button.

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => lvi.Focus()), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input);
```

Comment: If you want Keyboard focus try `Keyboard.Focus(lvi);` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```cs
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.IsSelected = true;
```

Hope that helps ;)